# Why we get negetive value when a date subtract from another using timespan

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, time

I want to get time difference of two dates.I use the following code

```
string starttime='2015/01/25';
string endtime='2015/02/25';


DateTime date1=convert.ToDateTime(starttime);
DateTime date2=convert.ToDateTime(endtime);
TimeSpan timediff= endtime.Subtract(starttime);
```

here I get negative time.why it is happen.then how can I get a Positive time

Comment: What values do you use for starttime and endtime?

Comment: is the end before the start? also.... `date1`  and `date2` seem to be irrelevant in the example code

Comment: [`DateTime.Subtract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx): "If the date and time of the current instance is earlier than *value*, the method returns a `TimeSpan` object that represents a negative time span"

Answer (score 4):

That is simply what you get if the `endtime` is *earlier* than (less-than) the `starttime`:

```
DateTime starttime = new DateTime(2005, 5, 8);
DateTime endtime = new DateTime(2005, 5, 7);
TimeSpan timediff = endtime.Subtract(starttime); // minus one day
```

Because... maths.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, your `endtime` is less than `starttime`. That's why you get negative value. `TimeSpan` has a method as [`Duration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of the current object.

By the way, it is not clear why you try to parse your `starttime` and `endtime` to `DateTime`. Since you used with `Subtract` with them, both seems a `DateTime` *already*.

Also if you don't have a custom structure as `convert`, the .NET Framework [`Convert` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) starts with upper case. (*Since C# is case sensitive as well*) That's why you need to use it as `Convert.ToDateTime` instead.

After your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30773777/2), your code won't *even* compile anymore. You need to use double quotes with your strings.

```
string starttime = "2015/01/25";
string endtime = "2015/02/25";
```

In this case, we see they are actually strings, not DateTime's. And you need to use `date1` and `date2` when you calculate your `TimeSpan`, not those strings. So your real code should be;

```
string starttime = "2015/01/25";
string endtime = "2015/02/25";

DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(starttime);
DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(endtime);
TimeSpan timediff = date1.Subtract(date2);
```

which returns `-31.00:00:00` since there are `31` days between these dates.